# Maximum of multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unpack, argument-unpacking

We can compute the element-wise maximum of 3 numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))       # any 4x5 array
B = np.maximum(A, A+7, A+2)     # working
```

But why doesn't `np.maximum` accept multiple arrays from an "unpacking"?

```
L = [np.roll(A, k, axis=0) for k in range(4)]     # 4 arrays: A shifted with different k
np.maximum(*L)
```

Error:

> ValueError: invalid number of arguments

After all, `L` is a Python list of Numpy array objects, so `*L` should unpack it for the `np.maximum` function call. Why doesn't it work?

PS: I also tried with `L = (...)` (which gives a generator) or `L = tuple(...)`, but we have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, `reduce` is the solution here:

```
np.maximum.reduce([np.roll(A, k, axis=0) for k in range(4)])
```

Comment: Yes the question was already answered & I am glad that it helped you. **Pardon** me for Flagging your question ^_^.

Comment: No problem for flagging as duplicate @Rocky_Mental, it's perfectly fine :)